# observerSingleEvent function not being ran with Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to run a function to be able to retrieve data from the realtime database with Firebase, however whenever I run the function; the observerSingleEvent part of my function will not run, I have tried putting a print statement within and it is not being run nor is the fields being read to the variable, any help would be beneficial.

```
func checkIfNewDay() -> Bool {
    print(self.currDate)
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    print("outside function")
    ref.child("user").child(userID!).child("dates").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        print("inside function")
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        print("just to make sure its going inside the function.  Delete after")
        self.lastDate = value?["lastSaveDate"] as? String ?? "Date Invalid"
        self.newLastDate = String(self.lastDate)
        if self.newLastDate != "Date Invalid" {
            print(self.lastDate)
        } else {
            print("Error, date not able to be recieved from the database")
            self.catchGetDateError = true
            self.saveCurrentDate()
        }
    })



    if (!self.catchGetDateError) {
        print(self.newLastDate, "newLastDate")
        print(self.currentDate, "currentDate")

        if (self.newLastDate == self.currentDate) {
            print("Day has not moved on.")
            return false
        } else {
            print("Day has moved on!")
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

I apologise for the really long function - was quite a weird one to write.

Comment: Does xcode write some errors in console?

Comment: It's impossible to return something from a function which contains an asynchronous task. You need a completion handler. And the last `if` expression must be moved into the completion block of `observeSingleEvent`.

Comment: btw give us a screen of your database. Because I'm pretty sure, that you have some mistake in your reference

Comment: @vadian he doesn't get into body of observing, if i have understood correctly

Comment: @VladPulichev Yes but this code does not work anyway.

Comment: Hi, here is a image of my database - http://imgur.com/a/eUPaK

also, I am quite new with Firebase so any help with my syntax and code structure to make this work would be very appreciated

and no errors are printed to the console

Comment: add print(userID!) before ref.child... etc. What does it show?

Comment: I tried printing that, and this was outputted:
H1MNSV6ljXPO9PfMs1LgxWyUPVr1

Comment: I just changed a line completely unrelated to the function and I ran in again, this is the entire console log:

https://pastebin.com/frvDcJjp (too long for the comments)  Whatever I just changed made a major difference and seems to have allowed to go inside, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: "inside function" u have it. Or u want this to work sync?

Comment: wait. I will write answer. I think i have understood you

Comment: I changed a variable in a different function, and it seems to be looping through the entire checkIfNewDay() function before it goes inside the observersingleevent, which means that the variable self.newLastDate is not updated to the database and as kept to a blank variable which I'm calling at the beginning of the VC - hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments I think I have understood, what do you want.

For getting this results like sync, you need to implement escaping. Like this:

```
func checkIfNewDay(completion: @escaping (_ isNew: Bool) -> Void) {
    print(self.currDate)
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    print("outside function")
    ref.child("user").child(userID!).child("dates").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        print("inside function")
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        print("just to make sure its going inside the function.  Delete after")
        self.lastDate = value?["lastSaveDate"] as? String ?? "Date Invalid"
        self.newLastDate = String(self.lastDate)
        if self.newLastDate != "Date Invalid" {
            print(self.lastDate)
            if (self.newLastDate == self.currentDate) {
                print("Day has not moved on.")
                completion(false)
            } else {
                print("Day has moved on!")
                completion(true)
            }
        } else {
            print("Error, date not able to be recieved from the database")
            self.catchGetDateError = true
            self.saveCurrentDate()
            completion(false)
        }
    })
}
```

So, now you can use your func:

```
checkIfNewDay(completion: { isNew in
     // do whatever you want. isNew will have info, that you need.
})
```

You should have it, because .observe functions work async. You should understand the idea.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @GaryTate glad to hear! gl